# Generated text file can be found by third party app in Download folder but not shown in Android's default Downloads app

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a download button, which saves a string in a .txt file and in Android's Downloads folder.

Now I can find this pgn.txt in the Download folder using third party apps like `Android File Transfer` or `File Explorer`. However, I don't know why the file is not showing in the Android's default app `Downloads`.

Anyone can help me with this? Thanks a lot!

Here is my code.

```
public void onPositiveButtonClicked(int dialogId, String input) {
                String str = "some string"
                File downloads = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
                try {
                    File pgnfile = new File(downloads.getAbsolutePath(), "pgn.txt");
                    FileWriter pgnwriter;
                    pgnwriter = new FileWriter(pgnfile);
                    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(pgnwriter);
                    out.write(str);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getContext(), new String[]{pgnfile.getAbsolutePath()}, null, new OnScanCompletedListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {

                        }
                    });
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(getContext().openFileOutput("config.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
                // outputStreamWriter.write(pgn);
                // outputStreamWriter.close();
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Downloads app only shows files downloaded via `DownloadManager`, not arbitrary files placed in the `DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS` location.